# Problems with relations in database

Tags: sql, database, django-models, model

I am creating a database for automatic posting service. I have users, each user has many channels, it is his own channels. But each channel also has many many users, as content authors for this channel. How can i create it in database structure. I tryied to create this structure, but i think it is wrong. [here is my structure as ER-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeFSU.png)

Comment: Can a user be the author of many channels?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, there are two independent relationships.
First, a user can own 0 (or 1) to many channels - so we put a foreign key inside Channel referencing User. (as you did)

Then users can make posts inside a channel. So the post table has a foreign key referencing Channel (where the post lives) and every post has an author: add a foreign key in Post referencing User.
This way, we have a many-to-many relationship between User and Channel (via the Post table). One user can contribute to many channels. One channel can have many contributors.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the relationship "author". Your tables should look like:

```
Profile (id_User)

Channel (id_Channel, id_User_Owner(FK), name_Channel)

Author (id_User(FK), id_Channel(FK))

Post (...)

Payment (...)
```

Comment: Yes, the "author" relationship is an **N:M** relationship that links `Profile` and `Channel`; so far it only has two foreign keys. So any profile can author any number of channels, and any channel can be authored by any number of profiles.